# Using Scala Arrays with abstract types

Tags: java, scala

As an example here's the boiled down code.

```
trait DataType {
    type DType
    // more stuff
}

object IntType extends DataType {
    type DType = Int
    // more stuff
}

trait Codec {
    val dtype: DataType
    // more stuff
}

class DenseCodec(val dtype: DataType) extends Codec {
    def get(size: Int) = new Array[dtype.DType](size)
}

val dense = new DenseCodec(IntType)

dense.get(4)
```

This will not compile:

`cannot find class tag for element type DenseCodec.this.dtype.DType
    def get(size: Int) = new Array[dtype.DType](size)
                         ^`

I know this has something to do with Arrays in Scala being special. I could use here something like Vector which will work fine but the project I'm working on is heavy on data processing and I would like to keep things as efficient as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will work

```
  def get(size: Int)(implicit tag: ClassTag[DataType]) = new Array[DataType](size)
```

Or using an equivalent context bound

```
  def get[DType: ClassTag](size: Int) = new Array[DType](size)
```

you could even replace `DType` with a template `T`.

`Array's` constructor actually takes an implicit parameter of type `ClassTag` and therefore you need to supply one, either implicitly or explicitly.

EDIT: Also worth noting that using `dtype.DType` will not work because `dtype` is of type `DataType` that has no concrete `DType` but only an abstract one. Funnily enough `dtype.type` will work just fine because at runtime `val dtype: DataType` is already an `IntType`.

EDIT2: If you want to propagate the type, I am afraid that the only way would be to use type classes.

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

object Types {
  trait DataType[A] {
    // more stuff
  }

  object IntType extends DataType[Int]

  object StringType extends DataType[String]

  trait Codec[B] {
    val dtype: DataType[B]
    // more stuff
  }

  class DenseCodec[B](val dtype: DataType[B]) extends Codec[B] {
    def get(size: Int)(implicit ct: ClassTag[B]) = new Array[B](size)
  }

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val denseInt = new DenseCodec(IntType)
    val arrInt = denseInt.get(4) //Array[Int]

    val denseString = new DenseCodec(StringType)
    val arrString = denseString.get(4) //Array[String]
  }
}
```

This way you can get rid of the `DType` and use the type class's type instead. You don't introduce any boilerplate because you wanted to define `IntType` and probably more types anyway.
Hope this one solves your problem :)

EDIT3: If you want to keep your `DType` just go with

```
trait DataType[A] {
  type DType = A
  // more stuff
}
```

and modify `get` definition

```
def get(size: Int)(implicit ct: ClassTag[B]) = new Array[dtype.DType](size)
```

But this way you will have a long type signature derived from `IntType`, `StringType` etc..

Comment: `dense.get(4)` returns Array[Nothing]. It will work when I do `dense[IntType.DType].get(4)` but that looks superfluous.

Comment: Of course it is - `DType` is just a type alias and in this case is defined in each class that you define e.g. `IntType`. You don't introduce a type hierarchy yourself. `IntType.DType` is just a fancy way of saying `Int` at compile time.

Comment: Updated answer. @marcin_koss

Comment: Thanks, this works. I read somewhere type members should be preferred but I guess it always depends on the problem at hand.

Comment: Yeah, it is tough. Updated it even further :D I suggest reading up Cats or Scalaz sources to get a hang of it. @marcin_koss